# android widget full width in samsung galaxy note

Tags: android, android-widget

I have developed a widget. The problem is it does not span the entire width in samsung galaxy note.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="120dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: can you explain clearly in detail?

Comment: When I add the widget on home page. The space remains on right side of the widget. I want it to take entire width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

hi Samsung Galaxy Note is large screen with xhdpi resolution. So you have to give support for large screens in android manifest.

Add this `android:largeScreens="true"` in supported screens in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: what is the width you have now?

Comment: @llango J: is samsung note is largescreens or xlargescreens ?

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake. I tried increasing minWidth but did not re-add the widget hence it did not take effect.

After increasing minWidth, I removed and re-added the widget now it spans across entire width.

Comment: But one thing i notice that if u set android:minWidth="300dp" then no widget apperas for smaller resolution device.